# Rails, Devise, and Mongo - Which versions do I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongomapper

I'm currently trying to get a Mongo database running alongside Devise.  I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and Ruby 1.9.3, mongo_mapper 0.11.0, devise 1.1.9, and devise-mongo_mapper 0.0.2.  I've referred to numerous sources online, but they seem to be invariably outdated.

A huge problem I'm facing right now involves devise-mongo_mapper.  With mongod running on the terminal, trying to run the rails server gives me the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:193:in `mailer=': undefined method `ref' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:195:in `<module:Devise>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
from /home/neilbasu/Desktop/rails_practice_app/onemoremongopractice/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I checked online and found this could be because my devise isn't updated.  Trying to update it gave me this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "devise":
  In Gemfile:
    devise-mongo_mapper (>= 0) ruby depends on
      devise (~> 1.1.0) ruby

    devise (2.0.4)
```

So basically, the older devise won't work, and the newest version isn't compatible with my current devise-mongo_mapper.  Is there any way around this?  Either a way to get all of these programs working together or a way to not need devise-mongo_mapper at all would be great.

Comment: Why don't you use [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org)? It is directly supported by Devise. No need for other gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [several of the forks](https://github.com/collectiveidea/devise-mongo_mapper/network).

They just bumped the version in the gemspec and the code probably works unchanged.

Comment: Thanks!  Made the changes on one of the forks and my server is now running.

Answer (score 0):

You can install whatever version of the gem you want using the `-v argument`.

`sudo gem install whatever -v 1.0.1`

Or you can look at the forks as Plastic Chicken suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error and running "**bundle update**" solved my problem.